# load values to java combo box from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jcombobox

I have created a jframe using net beans and add combo box to that. I just want to load values from one of my my sql table. I need entire field from that table to load to the combo box. what is the simplest code possible. (or the graphical method in netbeans).

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may either use the `Vector<T>`   or `ComboBoxModel` object. Take a look at [JCombobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) tutorial.

PS: You should have to use [mysql JDBC connector API](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to fetch the database result.